# How to extract record from json string to display in Jquery Datatable?

Tags: datatables, json.net

I'm fetching client records from the database and after concatenating the model class properties(**FirstName** and **LastName**) I converted these records in JSON string. My goal is to display these records in Jquery Datatable. I observed at debugging, all these records are in a single string causing the error "Requested unknown parameter".

At first, I tried to return a simple **JSON** return method `return Json(ClientList)` but it did not concatenate the model class properties.
 Thus, I used `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` to convert all the details by passing **ClientList** object and now scratching my head how to use this JSON String in Jquery Datatable as all the records are in this format **[{record 1 details..},{record 2 details..}, and so on]**.

**Model Class**

```cs
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public string FullName
        {
            get
            {
                return FirstName + " " + LastName;
            }
        }
```

**Controller**

```cs
public ActionResult GetClientList()
        {
            var ClientList = _context.Clients.ToList();
            //return Json(ClientList);

            string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(clientList);
            return Json(jsonData);
        }
```

**View**

```js
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#ClientTable").DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Client/GetClientList",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json",
                    "dataSrc": ""
                },
                "columns":
                    [
                        { "data": "Id" },
                        { "data": "FullName" }
                    ]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I want datatable to look like this:
Id | Name 
1  | ABC XYZ

Comment: Can you share a sample of your JSON, received user-end, so that we can suggest how to turn that into what you need?

Comment: Are there any delimiters between the details of each record so that you can use those to split details string into row columns?

Comment: **JSON Result** 
[{\"Id\":1,\"FirstName\":\"abc\",\"LastName\":\"xyz\",\"FullName\":\"abc xyz\"},{\"Id\":2,\"FirstName\":\"qwe\",\"LastName\":\"rty\",\"FullName\":\"qwe rty\"}]

Comment: It's because you're not returning the json in a format that datatables expects.  See [datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data)

Comment: It's rather strange, because your JS along with your JSON works perfectly in [test environment](https://codesandbox.io/s/jxlq54ol5?fontsize=14). Are you sure, your browser receives ajax response in the form you have shared (browser's developer's tools -> Network)?

Comment: Looks like you are converting into JSON format twice (escaped quote characters `\"`). I am not .NET expert but try using `return Json(ClientList);` or `return jsonData;` to avoid double JSON encoding.

Comment: @markpsmith , can u plz edit the above controller code for my ease. I really appreciate if u could do so

Comment: @SneakyBastard, yes I checked it and it works perfectly.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com, earlier, I was trying to convert records in JSON by using this `return Json(ClientList);` . After that, I comment out this piece of code bcz I was not getting the desired result.